# Triggering bootstrap navbar after page load using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6 and jQuery 1.11.3. I keep struggling with triggering [bootstrap's navbar](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/components/#navbar) using plain JavaScript/jQuery.

My application is giving me the following data structure. Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to change it. I can add neither classes nor ids nor anything else.

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://google.de">Stuff</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more link</a></li>
      </ul></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mgmt Reports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Notices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Liens</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">A long sub menu</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**What I have already done** in order to add the bootstrap navbar:

1. Adding the class `dropdown-menu` to all `ul` tags. 
   I used `$("ul ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");`to achieve that.
2. Adding the classes `nav navbar-nav` to the outermost `ul` tag. 
   I used `$("ul:first").addClass("nav navbar-nav");` to achieve that.
3. Adding a surrounding `div` with classes `collapse navbar-collapse`. This is not a problem as I'm able to edit the surrounding HTML.
4. Adding [jQuery Smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/) to get multilevel navbar working.

The classes are added nicely (the outcoming code looks good). This is the working jQuery code:

```
$("ul:first").addClass("nav navbar-nav");
$("ul ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");
$("ul:first").smartmenus({
    subIndicatorsText: '',
    subIndicatorsPos: 'append',
});
$(".sub-arrow").addClass("caret");
```

---

**EDIT**

The navbar is triggered. However, it is not equal to a navbar on which the same css classes are added manually (in HTML without JavaScript). It doesn't have the same functionality.

**Example 1:** A normal bootstrap navbar prevents the TopMenu items from being clicked on a mobile device. I.e. the 1st click on a mobile device on `<a href="http://google.com">Stuff</a>` opens the SubMenu. The 2nd click opens google. This doesn't seem to work when the classes are added using JavaScript.

**Example 2:** When I add the classes manually the submenus open to the bottom (dropdown). When the classes are added using jQuery the submenus open in right direction. The outcoming code looks the same.

**Question:**
What am I missing here? How can I trigger the bootstrap navbar using plain JavaScript or jQuery without touching the HTML and without losing functionality?

Comment: I don't think it's completely proper. For example by adding a surrounding DIV with collapse class, it all will get hidden. Please recheck the proper structure in the bootstrap docs.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. At the bottom of the HTML you provided you have an extra closing tag for a `li` element. This may be causing you problem. It is the third line up from the bottom in your example.

Comment: Actually, your HTML is malformed in a dirrerent way. Your second `li` element is closed before the `ul` that should be its child. This `ul` is then a child of another `ul`, which is invalid, and the extra `</li>` should be causing you an error. Remove the closing `li` tag (`</li`) from line 3 in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to create a "tree-control" using Bootstrap Collapse. Bootstrap Collapse is typically used to make "accordion" controls instead. A "tree-control" theoretically could be created with Bootstrap collapse using `panel-groups` and declaring `data-parent`, but this does not match the HTML you've provided that you say you cannot edit.

What I did find is [**this**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-plain-collapsible-tree-menu), which appears to be pretty promising for turning your un-editable `ul-struct` into a working tree-control. I tried making a script that could dynamically update your structure and make this work, but I didn't have much luck. I can't spend much time on it, but [**here is my work**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/u1dfotpt/5/) if you would like to poke aroud with it. I hope this helps.

Also, there are two major errors with what you have provided. One, on the third line of the HTML provided you have a closing tag for the `li` element there. There is a closing tag later in the HTML for the same element, I presume, and you must remove the closing tag on line 3 of your HTML so that your `li` can encapsulate the following `ul`. I hope this was a copy-paste error and that you can edit this part, because this error will break your project.

Also, the Bootstrap directives of `collapse` and `dropdown-menu` don't seem to work nice together. In all of my testing, if I have a working `collapse` on an element and I add the class `dropdown-menu` to it, it no longer listens to the `data-toggle`. I would suggest removing the `dropdown-menu` piece from your process, it appears to be unnecessary.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it's semantically the same as `$("ul ul")...`

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Of course it is semantically the same, yet it is working. If this doesn't work for you, then your problem stems from something in your project that you are not showing us. Did you include everything correctly?. Please review [**this working JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/u1dfotpt/).

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you were having an issue adding the classes. My apologies. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and your detailed feedback. I appreciate your work. You were right, my html was malformed. I fixed it and added jQuery smartmenus to get the navbar working. However, there are still differences in the behaviour of the navbar when the classes are added via jQuery. I tried to explain that in my Edit. Anyway, thank you for your answer.